# Animate selected text

Tags: vba, animation, powerpoint

I'm trying to animate selected text in a presentation.

I found a way to animate a shape, but not only a portion of it.

```vb
Dim effNew As Effect
Dim shpFirst As Shape

Set shpFirst = ActivePresentation.Slides(ActiveWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex).Shapes(4)
                                                    
Set effNew = ActivePresentation.Slides(ActiveWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex).TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect _
    (Shape:=shpFirst, effectId:=msoAnimEffectBounce)
```

There are two properties that might help, but they are read-only:

```vb
effNew.TextRangeStart
effNew.TextRangeLength
```

Comment: Text is not animated except for appearing in sequence (if you set that). It's the containing _shapes_ that are animated. So it's not possible to animate a portion of text unless that portion is in its own shape.

Comment: Hi John, But from th UI i can do it, so i would expect to be able to do the same programmatically. Otherwise is a limitation in Vba that i can't understand!

Comment: I can't apply a Bounce animation to selected text in PowerPoint. Please link to a sample that illustrates your claim.

Comment: Here is a link. https://wsi.li/dl/BwEWwvmQiDrEfvJT5/ The effect I'm interested in is transparency... the first example i found was with bouncing, I don't think it makes a difference.